# How to set a value in a variable column name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

How do I set a value in a variable column name? For some context, I am writing a function to be used as a trigger which sets a variable column to a constant value. To be used as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER always_6_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE always_6('col1');
```

The above would result in the following rows all having a `col1` value of 6. So for example:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (6, 2), (null, 9), (null, 10), (7, 2);
```

Would result in:

```
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
| 6    | 2    |
| 6    | 9    |
| 6    | 10   |
| 6    | 2    |
```

Or if using the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER always_6_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE always_6('col2');
```

And the same insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (6, 2), (null, 9), (null, 10), (7, 2);
```

The table would look like:

```
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
| 6    | 6    |
| null | 6    |
| null | 6    |
| 7    | 6    |
```

How would I write the `always_6` function?

**Edit:** To better explain the use case, the constant value would be `current_setting('user_id')` (or something alike). And the column name would be things like `author_id` and `user_id`. The thinking being that a user could never add for data which was not their own.

Comment: Can you give an example or two of the different implementations of how you would use this and the expected result?

Comment: Okay, provided examples. Is that good or do you want more?

Comment: Yes, that's great detail.  Writing the always_6 function seems doable, but I don't understand how you control which trigger is used.  Do you already have that worked out?  Is only one trigger going to exist at any given time?

Comment: The column name is constant on a per-table basis. I added another piece at the end better describing the use case. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your function to produce [dynamically generated SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

The EXECUTE command takes a string as input and executes it as SQL, so it would look something like this:

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('UPDATE mytable SET %I='constantvalue' WHERE condition', colname);
```

Here I have used the [FORMAT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function to prepare a string with the value of `colname` substituted in where the column name would go. `condition` would be some valid WHERE clauses to select the record to update.

If the value of `colname` could come from an external source (ie. user supplied data) then you would have to be very careful to validate it beforehand, otherwise you might create an SQL injection vector.

Comment: Will this work to change the value on the `NEW` object?

Comment: If you're going to bother using `FORMAT`, you should use the appropriate escaping format, which is `%I` for an identifier. So `FORMAT('UPDATE mytable SET %I='constantvalue' WHERE condition', colname);` Using `%s` is no better than concatenating the string together with `||`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic query to do this with conditional check on the passed parameter value to the input parameter of the stored procedure.

Comment: As this is needed on insert, can I use this on the `NEW` object?

Answer (score 0):

I think I oversimplified the task based on the initial description, but would something like this work?  You can't pass a parameter to a trigger function, but you mentioned the parameter was the result of another function `current_setting('user_id')`, so is it possible to roll the two concepts together like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION always_6()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  current_user_id varchar;
BEGIN

  current_user_id := current_setting('user_id');

  if current_user_id = 'test1' then
    new.col_1 := 6;
  elsif current_user_id = 'test2' then
    new.col_2 := 6;
  end if;

  return NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, the `current_setting` would be used instead of the 6. So this would not work. Also there are many more tables which complicates things.

Comment: Aah, I see.  Is the data being populated via an application, or are the users doing the inserts themselves via psql?

Comment: Short answer: user's insert for themselves. Long answer: I'm using an HTTP REST API library [PostgREST](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest) where the user will insert for themselves.

Comment: Wow, man...  I only wish I could upvote your question a second time.